# Manipulating closure scoped dom element inside promise callback

Tags: javascript, dom, promise, dom-manipulation, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am writing a Chrome extension to modify site contents.
I am fetching some data from a backend API through the background script and then updating the website contents to reflect that data.
Initially, I was confused that after modifying the elements' innerHTML the change wasn't reflected in the page.
After some debugging I found out element.isConnected is false inside the callback function.
Now, I'm unable to figure out a way to fix this and update the DOM elements.
The basic outline is that I'm reading rows of data from a table and for each row I'm reading the cell contents and updating cell contents after the API returns. Each row of the table is stored as an element of an array and is operated on by a map function.

Here is my relevant code:

```
let tableRows = document.querySelectorAll(".tablerow");
let tableRowsArray = Array.from(tableRows);
tableRowsArray.map(function (row) {
  let tableCells = row.innerHTML.split("</td>");
  (async () => {
    console.log(row.isconnected);                         //returns true here
    const response = await chrome.runtime.sendMessage(/*{some data}*/);
    let fetcheda = response.a;
    tableCells.splice(12, 0, "<td><output>" + fetcheda + "</output></td>");
    console.log(row.isConnected);                         //returns false here
    row.innerHTML = tableCells.join("");
    console.log(row);                                     //the correct row is modified correctly but does not reflect in the page
  })();
});
```

I tried .then() for the promise instead of await and the problem remains. I also replace chrome.runtime.sendMessage() with a timeout promise and the problem remains the same.
Here is the code using .then():

```
let tableRows = document.querySelectorAll(".tablerow");
let tableRowsArray = Array.from(tableRows);
tableRowsArray.map(function (row) {
  let tableCells = row.innerHTML.split("</td>");
  console.log(row.isconnected);                           //returns true here
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage(/*{some data}*/).then((response) => {
    let fetcheda = response.a;
    tableCells.splice(12, 0, "<td><output>" + fetcheda + "</output></td>");
    console.log(row.isConnected);                         //returns false here
    row.innerHTML = tableCells.join("");
    console.log(row);                                     //the correct row is modified correctly but does not reflect in the page
  })
});
```

I believe that somehow some properties of the row variable are stripped inside the .then() callback as row now becomes closure scoped instead of local scoped. I would like to know some way to be able to modify the DOM inside the .then() callback. And I also cannot simply get the respective row again  for which the API request was made.

Comment: It means the site removes the element and adds another in its place. You can repeat querySelectorAll and get the new elements after await/then. To find the right row you would remember its old contents, then find the matching one in the new elements.

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm for chiming in. To check this I made some changes to the row before calling chrome.runtime.sendMessage(). These changes are retained on the web page. So, I doubt that the element is changing during the time of the async call

Comment: If the element shows your changes then either its isConnected is true (the site isn't always swapping the element) or the site reads the changes and preserves them in the new element.